# Azure Error While Adding Certificate to Key Vault

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I just bought `App Service Certificate` from `Azure Portal`. To use it configurations must be made and I completed Step 2 and 3.

However, when I am trying to Import certificate into `Key Vault` for secure administrator, I got the exception:

```
The parameter keyVaultCsmId has an invalid value
```

I couldn't find any solution on the internet. Is there anyone who has got the same error?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking question! In Azure Key Vault, supported certificate formats are PFX and PEM.

•   .pem file format contains one or more X509 certificate files.

•   .pfx file format is an archive file format for storing several cryptographic objects in a single file i.e. server certificate (issued for your domain), a matching private key, and may optionally include an intermediate CA.

Certificates used by App Service first needs to be converted to (and marked as) application/x-pkcs12.
Re-importing the cert from a pfx file with the --password parameter (az keyvault certificate import), and after that import it from the key vault to the webapp might help.
You may refer to [this Blog](https://blog.petergerritsen.nl/2019/03/14/arm-deployment-error-when-changing-keyvaultsecretname)  might be helpful.

Also, look if Cert and the Key Vault are in their original resource group.

Additional details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/24/Deploying-Azure-Web-App-Certificate-through-Key-Vault.html